# Is it possible to pass props/data to React components embedded in 'plain' HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I need to do some updates to a very old school website.  Currently the layout is table based and hand-coded.  My thought was to use React do do away with some of the repetitive coding, specifically loop through an array of data and construct the table rows with JSX.  I see that it's possible to embed React components in HTML here -- https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html -- but I'm not sure how to make those components reusable, that is, I'm not sure how to pass props to them from the HTML file.

My plan is to read data arrays from a file specific to each html page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data_page_x.js"></script>
```

and then pass it to the component, which would read it as a prop, then spit out the table rows.

Is this possible?  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: if the data is already laid out in the html document, you could use plain javascript (or jquery) to query for the elements with the data, loop through them, construct js objects, and pass them as props to react components. This becomes easier especially because you said the data is laid out in a table format, you could find the parent element for each row and get the right data from it's children. Each row becomes a js object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
const initialData = document.getElementById('initial-data').textContent; 

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyReactElement initialData={JSON.parse(initialData)} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Or if you are not using JSX, you can pass data to ReactElement using `React.createElement`

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

https://cdn.rawgit.com/gaearon/0b180827c190fe4fd98b4c7f570ea4a8/raw/b9157ce933c79a4559d2aa9ff3372668cce48de7/LikeButton.js

Passing data using `React.createElement`

```
 const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container'); 
 const e = React.createElement;
 ReactDOM.render(
   e(
    LikeButton,
    {initialData: JSON.parse(initialData)}
  ), domContainer);
```